# Securing PHP code. Need some tips

Tags: php, ioncube, code-security

I want to encode my codes with ionCube. But I do not know exactly how to prevent users from cracking it without encoding.

So I need some tips.

My project is a MVC.

Everything starts in index.php and it calls core.php and running goes.

How should I include files. How can I ensure that when a file is called it is the original one?

I know there is some PHP functions that print out function names, etc. I need to prevent this.

Users include index.php file from another file and try to get variables like using `var_dump($_GLOBALS);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [get_included_files](http://php.net/get_included_files) function to see if there are other files included. But the best way is of course to trust your customers and regulate what they can and cannot do with your code through contracts.

Comment: it's not a problem if they see which files included. I am gonna hash all file names using `sha1()` So I need to prevent user to change the included files code and use of `var_dump($_GLOBALS);`

Comment: +1 If you don't trust your customers to follow your license agreement, then PHP probably shouldn't be your first choice for a closed system. Best use a compiled solution to protect your IP.